# Trouble writing in a system of equations, while aligning its coefficients

Tags: equations, align, text

The part above the `hrule` is what I have when aligning the coefficients. What I would like to do now is to write `\min`and `\text{s.a.}` and also add the last line, i.e., `x_i \geqslant 0, \forall i \in [7]`. I am having some trouble doing so without messing up the alignment of the coefficients. Below I leave my code for the system **ABOVE** the `hrule`. Thanks for all the help in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \sysdelim..\systeme{-10x_1+57x_2+9x_3+24x_4,
                            0.5x_1-5.5x_2-2.5x_3+9x_4+x_5=0, 
                            0.5x_1-1.5x_2-0.5x_3+x_4+x_6=0,
                            x_1+x_7 = 1}
    \end{equation*}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I will update it to exactly what I have. **UPDATED** already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs two `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary/relational operators
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
  \min \\[0.5ex] \text{s.a.} \\ \\ \\ \\
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}{  r *{7}{Cr} }
-10x_1 &+&  57x_2 &+&   9x_3 &+& 24x_4 \\[0.5ex]
0.5x_1 &-& 5.5x_2 &-& 2.5x_3 &+&  9x_4 &+& x_5 & &     & &     &=& 0 \\
0.5x_1 &-& 1.5x_2 &-& 0.5x_3 &+&   x_4 & &     &+& x_6 & &     &=& 0 \\
   x_1 & &        & &        & &       & &     & &     &+& x_7 &=& 1 \\
\multicolumn{15}{l}{\phantom{-10}x_i \geqslant 0 \ \forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,7\} }
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I have further arrays on my document will this code mess them up? Thanks for your answer! I am asking this because I have indeed more arrays in my document, with specific colseps. **UPDATE** It didn't mess them up. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Seabourn - Note that the `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}` and `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}` are located inside the `equation*` environment. As the scope of these two instructions is this particular `equation*` environment, they will not affect the appearance of subsequent `array` environments.

Comment: +1 see comments under my answer:-)

Answer (score 4):

We can trick `systeme` into thinking that the first coefficients in the first two equations have the words.

The last condition can be set in a separate line of an `array`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}
\sysdelim..
\newcommand{\FIRST}[1]{\makebox[5em][s]{$\min\hfill{#1}$}}
\newcommand{\SECOND}[1]{\makebox[5em][s]{s.a.\hfill${#1}$}}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \systeme{
   {\FIRST{-10}}x_1 +  57x_2 +   9x_3 + 24x_4,
  {\SECOND{0.5}}x_1 - 5.5x_2 - 2.5x_3 +  9x_4 + x_5 = 0, 
             0.5x_1 - 1.5x_2 - 0.5x_3 + x_4   + x_6 = 0,
                x_1 +                           x_7 = 1
  }\\
\hspace*{5em} x_i\ge0,\forall i\in[7]
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure this alignment galore is easy to read, though.

Answer (score 3):

A version just using `amsmath`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{9}
  \min\quad&&  -10&x_1&{}+57&x_2&{}+9&x_3&{}+24&x_4&\\
  \text{s.a}\quad&&  0.5&x_1&{}-5.5&x_2&{}-2.5&x_3&{}+9&x_4&{}+{}&x_5&&&&&&=0\\ 
             &&     0.5&x_1&{}-1.5&x_2&{}-0.5&x_3&{}+{}&x_4&&&{}+{}&x_6&&&&=0\\
              &&          &x_1&&&&&&&&&&&{}+{}&x_7& &= 1\\
              \rlap{$\displaystyle x_i \geq0, \forall i \in[7]$}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to align the `+` and `-` signs aswell using this method? (just like what I have). Thanks for your answer and time!

Comment: yes sure I didn't really consider that I just placed the operator in the same cell as the follwing coefficient, you could  have the operators in their own column by adding some more &

Comment: Do you think you can give me a small example on how to? I am trying but I am having some trouble doing so

Comment: actually having got that far it might be simpler to use array and centred columns, I'll post another version but it's late may be tomorrow

Comment: Well, @Mico already posted an answer using what I believe to be what you just stated! Thanks for your help though, I wish I could pin two answer as correct!

Comment: @Seabourn ah yes saves me the bother (and I think it's an hour later for Mico so I've no excuse:-)

Answer (score 3):

I exploited the friendly relationship between `systeme`'s parser and math operators to be able to include the `min` and the *s.a.*.
The code is really ugly but if you want to use `systeme`, I think you'll hardly get better than that. Thus, I'd highly recommend to use one of the other solutions on this thread.

**MWE:**

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sa}{\text{\textit{s.a.}}}
\sysaddeqsign{\geqslant}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\syssubstitute{{x_8}{x_i}}
\sysdelim..
\systeme{%
{\min\quad \-10}x_1+57x_2+9x_3+24x_4,
{\sa\quad \ 0.5}x_1-5.5x_2-2.5x_3+9x_4+x_5=0,
0.5x_1-1.5x_2-0.5x_3+x_4+x_6=0,
x_1+x_7 = 1, 
x_8 \geqslant 0@{\forall i\in [7]}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image: LaTeX output]